# Open a map URL with MapKit

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I was wondering how can I open a google map URL with MapKit ?

this code exit the application and shows the location but I want shows on my mapView.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

Answer (score 1):

MapKit supports Geolocation - so how about something like this:

```
CLLocation *sanFran = [CLLocation locationUsingForwardGeoLocation:@"San Francisco, Califronia"];
```

This returns a CLLocation which you can then show on your map view.

Have a look at the [World Cities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WorldCities/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009466) sample code (iOS dev membership required) which shows how to animate an MKMapView to coordinates.

**Edited to add**

[There are ways to get the Lat-long with Google Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aObtaining_geographic_coordinates#Google_tools). You can use these to create a CLLocation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebview to load the contents of the url. Create a webView and initialise as follows:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino";
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Yeah you should add this webview as a subview to your main view.

Comment: sorry I am dealing with `MapKit` and my outlet is `MapView` not webView :)